# Understanding inner function with this in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently started to learn Javascript while doing some experiments with code stuck in this code:

```
var k = {
    ab: "hi",
    func: function() {
        console.log("inner1" + this.ab);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner2 " + this.ab)
        }())
    }
};
k.func();
```

This code giving me result "inner1 hi" and "inner2 undefined".

I'm not getting the reason why its `undefined` in second `console.log`?

Comment: function inside ( .. ()) ,known as IIFE, has window as context (this), but you has not defined ab in window object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `this` of a function is bound when you call it, depending on how you call it. Calling it as a value instead of a property – `(expression)()` instead of `object.method()` – will result in `this` being set to the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode.

There are two methods on function objects that call the function with an explicitly-specified `this`: [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). You can use the former here.

```
(function() {
    console.log("inner2 " + this.ab);
}.call(this));
```

That will forward the calling function’s `this` to the inner function.

Alternatively, you can just assign `this` to a variable.

```
var that = this;

(function() {
    console.log("inner2 " + that.ab);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer this is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
var k = {
    ab: "hi",
    func: function() {
        console.log(this,"inner1" + this.ab);
        (function() {
            console.log(this,"inner2 " + this.ab)
        }())
    }
};
k.func();
```

Executing the anonymous function changes the instance, to persist the context do:

```
var k = {
    ab: "hi",
    func: function() {
        console.log("inner1" + this.ab);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner2 " + this.ab)
        }.bind(this).call())
    }
};
k.func();
```

Comment: Not passing anything to call is a bit redundant; you can just do `.bind(this)()`. (If it’s for clarity’s sake… maybe assign it to something instead.)

Answer (score 2):

@minitech and @Issac very well explained the issue and solution. Another method to get property at any level is by object. In your code it is:

```
var k = {
    ab: "hi",
    func: function() {
        console.log("inner1" + this.ab);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner2 " + k.ab)
        }())
    }
};

k.func();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any reference for using `this` in second function. Instead you can use:

```
(function() {
    console.log("inner2 " + this.ab)
}.call(this))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example 'this' means two different things based on **scope**. You could play with this sample code. Maybe it would help you to understand the basics.

```
var k = {
    ab: "hi",
    func: function() {
        var me = this; // save 'meaning of this' in variable me.
        console.log("inner1" + this.ab);
        (function() {
            console.log("inner2 " + me.ab)
        }())
    }
};
k.func();
```